# Выделение нужного слова в CKeditor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor, bbcode

В общем, я слегка запуталась, может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как правильно организовать такой функционал.

Суть в следующем. У меня на сайте люди могут выкладывать свои статьи. Добавляют они их через ckeditor, который генерирует текст с bb-кодами. Другие люди эти самые статьи читают и, если видят орфографические ошибки, выделяют их и отправляют сообщение об этом автору. При этом, как показывает практика, в каждой статье может быть с десяток таких сообщений, в т.ч. и от разных читателей.

Для того, чтобы реализовать такой фукнционал, я сохраняю у себя номер абзаца и номер слова в предложении, в котором есть ошибка (выделяется именно "словами", а не строкой). Может быть, это неправильно, но мне показалось в какой-то момент наилучшим решением, т.к. не учитываются bb-коды (что было бы, если бы фиксировался номер символа) и не мешаются повторы слов (что было бы, если бы я запоминала конкретную фразу), а так же это дает возможность выбрать несколько слов в разных частях текста (например, если один кусок статьи противоречит другому).

И вот, когда автор статьи заходит по определенной ссылке, я выдаю ему тот же текст его статьи с пометками, что ошибка тут тут и тут (в таких-то словах) и комментарии пользователей, которые на эту ошибку указали (в чем ошибка и как ее исправить). НО. В данный момент человек, посмотрев эту страницу со списком указанных ошибок, должен перейти на редактирование и там, сверяясь опять же по списку, должен эти ошибки исправить. Это, очевидно, не есть гуд. Мне бы нужно было бы как-то совместить на одной странице редактор и текст с выводом ошибок.

Конечно, первой мыслью было выделять нужное в самом ckeditor'е, но это 1) сложно, нужно в нем досконально разбираться и писать модули 2) в результат вывалит не bb-код, а какую-нибудь ерунду с текстом этих ошибок внутри, опять же это нужно как-то чистить 3) если привязать ошибку к слову, то, когда человек это слово удалить, чтобы ошибку исправить, то и ошибка не будет видна. В общем, это как-то мне показалось слишком заумно и с множеством подводных камней.

Второй вариант - раз уж у меня есть привязка по номеру абзаца, то логично было бы сделать кнопку "редактировать абзац", через которую редактировался бы конкретный абзац, одновременно человек видел бы исходный текст с ошибками и все нужно исправил бы в абзаце. Но так как весь текст сохраняется как один текстовый блок, а не отдельными абзацами, я боюсь и тут возникновения разнообразных ошибок. К тому же, авторы, как на зло, очень любят расставлять пустые абзацы, и я боюсь, что они могут стать так же источником ошибок. Но это все же вариант.

Третий вариант: похож на второй, с той разницей, что можно использовать встроенный в ckeditor механизм редактирования не сходя с места (двойной клик - и вместо абзаца ckeditor). У него те же подводные камни, что и у второго, да и текст заменяется на редактор, а человек может забыть, где чего хотел поправить.

И последний вариант - как-то на странице совместить текст и редактор, чтобы при этом каждая строчка совпадала в одном и в другом, чтобы в обычном тексте посмотреть, что написали комментаторы, а в редакторе - исправить все всем скопом.

В общем, жду совета и вообще мнений о том, как это сделать правильно, или как сделать просто, не замарачиваясь.

Comment: Как вариант - подложить оригинальный текст под прозрачный редактор. В оригинальном тексте выделить ошибки. При редактировании делать проверку на возможные исправления слова и сразу же изменять подложку с исправленным текстом.

Просто тут получится только топорным размещением оригинального текста около редактора.

Comment: Мне кажется, что такой вариант был бы довольно сложен: чтобы текст не "двоился", пришлось бы очень быстро отслеживать изменения в нем и быстро вносить изменения в фон. К тому же, я не уверена, что у ckeditor'а есть возможность сделать прозрачным текстовую область так, чтобы панель редактирования осталась при этом нормальной.

К тому же, остается проблема с выводом. У меня сейчас в тексте выделяется слово, но нужно ведь еще по клику на него вывести дополнительные данные: как исправить, по какому правилу, в чем вообще проблема. На фоне это сделать не получится.

Comment: показывать на странице, где редактор, список ошибок в статье... или даже просто рядом в двух столбцах - один с выделенными ошибками, другой с редактором. на ошибки повесьте какой-нить способ их помечать как исправленные (наведение, галочки - "ошибка исправлена", "не ошибка" - второе опционально, чтобы может быть отлавливать автоматически всяких вандало-троллей)